# A question on BRST current of the Bosonic string, why we choose $c(z)$ as generator?

Tags: string-theory, conformal-field-theory, gauge-invariance, brst

I'm new to the forum, I will try to make my asking as clear as possible.

I'm currently writing a 40-minutes talk on the BRST quantization of the Bosonic string, mostly following Polchinski's Book. The author at page 131 (chapter 4.3) shows the BRST transformation for $X^{\mu}$ and the $b,c$ ghosts. Then reading from $$\delta_B X^{\mu} = i \epsilon \left(c\partial X^{\mu}\right)\tag{4.3.1a}$$ (I'm just showing the holomorphic part) that $X^{\mu}$ transforms as under a conformal gauge transformation with $ v(z) = c(z) $, the explicit form for the $X$-ghosts system's current is computed as $$j_b(z) = c(z)T(z) = c(z)T^x(z) + \frac{1}{2}:c(z)T^g(z): + \frac{3}{2}\partial^2 c(z).\tag{4.3.3}$$ Then using the Ward identity one can recognize the BRST transformation for an operator $O(z)$ from the first-order poles in the $JO$ OPE.

What I want to do is to follow the inverse path i.e. I'm trying to recover the BRST transformation for the worldsheet fields starting directly from the conserved current and extracting them from the $JO$ OPE, but I don't know how to state $v(z) = c(z)$ a priori in the formula for the current. I've found some naive explanation which involve the BRST algebra closure, other mention the operator-state mapping but I do not get the point. If I've understood , I want to study the change of the fields in the action under a conformal transformation and impose as constraint that the ghosts excitation kill the matter ones so that the missing equation of motion that we lost when gauge fixing the action are still satisfied on physical states. How does enter here the special choice $v(z) = c(z)$?

I'm pretty new to CFTs, and also need to stress some other fact: The Ward identity involves the residue of the first order pole, but why other poles are neglected?